# How to set FloatingActionButton's background transparent in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

[image: FloatingActionButton]

How to set the background of `FloatingActionButton` transparent which is blocking the `ListView` ?

Here is my code :

```
FloatingActionButton(
    isExtended: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {}
)
```

Here is the structure of `body` of `Scaffold` :

```
body : new Column (
           children : <Widget>[
               new Expanded (
                   child : new ListView.builder() //ListView.builder
               ), //Expanded

               new FloatingActionButton () //FloatingActionButton
           ] //<Widget>[]
        ) //Column
```

I also tried wrapping it with a `Container` and then applying container's background transparent, but it didn't work.

And also how to align it to the `bottom|end` of parent (`body` of `Scaffold`) ?

Comment: How have you used the `FloatingActionButton`? If it is used in the `floatingActionButton:` `Scaffold` property, as it name implies, it floats above the body, so you shouldn't do anything special.

Comment: @chemamolins Inside`Scaffold`, there is an `appBar`, after that inside the `body`, main widget is `Column`, inside `Column` first widget is  `Expanded` containing `ListView`, and second widget is `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set it in the `floatingActionButton:` `Scaffold` property, as in the example project created by flutter create command.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: How can I put more than one `FloatingActionButtons` ? The `Scaffold` doesn't seem to accept more than one.

Comment: You can use a Column or Row in the `floatingActionButton:`property. And inside put two `FloatingActionButton` widgets.